# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ';' or ',' in ./dbdrivers/odbc.php IN $$args[1]

Tags: php

When I changed from php 5.6 to php 7.4 I am getting this error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ';' or ',' in ./dbdrivers/odbc.php IN $$args[1]

```
function &db_fetch_row ($args=array()){
     global $$args[1];

     switch(count($args)) {
     case 2:
             return (odbc_fetch_into($args[0], $args[1]));
     default:
             return (odbc_fetch_array($args[0]));
     }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does `global $$args[1];` do?

Comment: There is so much bad practice packed into this function that it's hard to know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify either

```
${$args[1]}
```

or

```
${$args}[1]
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Or just delete that line, since it has absolutely no bearing on the rest of the function.